# AdjustTokenPrivileges Failed with Error 1300 ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, mfc, snmp

I have developed SNMP extension DLL to perform some operations like Shutdown,Restart,etc Remotely.It is working fine with XP.Now I am migrating the DLL for Windows 7.I have read the document "impact of session-0 isolation" from MSDN and followed the instructions for DLL migration.For example, I have followed the instructions in the link [How To ShutDown the System - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and coded the same for the shutdown operation. But "AdjustTokenPrivileges" always returning Error:1300 Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.

Is there any way to solve this error? How do I enable the shutdown privilege for Windows 7 Using VC++?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one: assign the privileges to the caller (requires logoff before it takes effect). This requires the admin of the computer or the domain/AD to act. You can also do it programatically with `LsaAddAccountRights()` and `LsaRemoveAccountRights()`.

Consider this: every user has a set of assigned privileges. Any assigned ones can be enabled or disabled for a token representing this user. What you are trying to do is to enable a privilege that was never assigned to the user in the first place. Therefore it cannot be enabled/activated.

However, I suggest you post your code, because it is very unusual that a local user cannot shut down the system. This privilege is usually granted to everyone logging on locally by default.

Comment: is it possible to add the shutdown privilege to the user manually using group policy?????

Comment: @Eshwar: sure. Run `secpol.msc` then go to `Local Policies` -> `User Rights Assignment` and then "Shut down the system" ...

Comment: I have added "Everyone" and my current user to "Shut down the system".. But the same error occurs.

Comment: As which user does it run (the service)? You'll under normal circumstances have to consider the the user and groups as which a service is running. But this can be configured, so there is no general answer without more information.

Comment: @Eshwar: this account most certainly has the privilege assigned. It's the account representing the machine itself. Either you are not saying something important (such as you're trying to shut down a *remote* machine) or some thing on your development system is severely messed up. Given I have spent so much time on this and you have not even provided a code snippet as I requested, it's hard to tell whether *you* are interested in a resolution yourself.

Comment: i have used the same code from msdn as i mentioned before.. Nothing i have modified.

Comment: By elimination that would only leave a messed up system as a reason unless you are leaving out important details. If you try to shut down the local system on which the service is running and it's running as `LocalSystem` it *will* be able to shut down the system. On a vanilla system this *will* work.